# Azure DevOps Custom Work Item - Created By field validation problem

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a new inherited process and a custom Work Item Type - "User Story". I then added ADO system's 'Created By' field to my fieldset
[User Story Fieldset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l8Bj.png)

And then created a rule to set the value on creation
[User Story Created By value Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZhaD.png)

However, when I go to enter a new User Story, the validation won't let me Save:
[Validation for Author field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDelB.png)

Note that the 'Author' came from the label I had previously used for this field:
[Label field Created By to Author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flrLT.png)

Comment: Do you check my answer?If you have any question,please kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message `Field 'Author' cannot be empty`, I think you should customize a field named `Author` and set the field as `Required` in `Options`.

[image]

If you don't find the Author field in the Work Item page, it may be due to the selection of `Hide from layout`.

[image]

[image]

Through the test, The field name displayed in the error message has nothing to do with the label. Even if you name the label of Created By field as Author, the error message should be displayed as `Field 'Created By' cannot be empty` instead of `Field 'Author' cannot be empty`.

So you can check whether the situation I mentioned above caused your problem .

Comment: Lin - THANK YOU! I was able to work around it by adding the Author (custom) field back to my fieldset, and then Hiding from Layout as not-required.